# woocommerce why when I create attributes and values for them in one query - values are not created

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I'm working at plugin that parces products from JSON. Before parcing it creates attributes (if they don't exist) that I need to parce those products. During parcing plugin creates values for those attributes. Thought I have a problem with that because when I parce for the first time (withought these attributes) - my attribute values are not being saved but when those attributes are already created - everything is fine. What's the problem? This is code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Woocommerce JSON Parser :)
Plugin URI: https://example.com/
Description: Плагин для создания категорий и атрибутов
Version: 1.0
Author: Sasha
Author URI: https://example.com/
License: GPL2
*/

// Добавляем пункт меню в админку
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Woocommerce JSON Parser :)', 'Woocommerce JSON Parser :)', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin', 'my_plugin_page', 'dashicons-admin-plugins', 99);
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');

// Выводим страницу плагина
function my_plugin_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Woocommerce JSON Parser :)</h1>
        <input type="text" id="category-input" placeholder="Введите ссылку">
        <button id="parse-button" class="button">Парсить</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#parse-button').on('click', function() {
                var link = $('#category-input').val();
                var category = getParameterByName('category', link);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                    data: {
                        action: 'my_plugin_parse',
                        category: category,
                        link: link
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#result').append(response);
                    }
                });
            });

            // Функция для получения значения параметра из URL
            function getParameterByName(name, url) {
                if (!url) url = window.location.href;
                name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
                var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
                    results = regex.exec(url);
                if (!results) return null;
                if (!results[2]) return '';
                return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

function create_attribute_item($name, $slug, $taxonomy) {
    // Check if the term already exists
    $existing_term = get_term_by('slug', $slug, $taxonomy);
    
    if ($existing_term instanceof WP_Term) {
      // Term already exists, return its ID
      return $existing_term->term_id;
    } else {
      // Term does not exist, create a new one
      $insert_res = wp_insert_term(
        $name,
        $taxonomy,
        array(
          'description' => '',
          'slug' => $slug
        )
      );
  
      if (is_wp_error($insert_res)) {
        return $insert_res->get_error_message();
      } else {
        $term_id = $insert_res['term_id'];
        return $term_id;
      }
    }
  }
  

// Обработка AJAX запроса
add_action('wp_ajax_my_plugin_parse', 'my_plugin_parse');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_plugin_parse', 'my_plugin_parse');
function my_plugin_parse() {
    $category = isset($_POST['category']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['category']) : '';
    $link = isset($_POST['link']) ? esc_url_raw($_POST['link']) : '';

    if (empty($category)) {
        echo 'Ошибка: Не указана категория.';
        wp_die();
    }

    if (empty($link)) {
        echo 'Ошибка: Не указана ссылка.';
        wp_die();
    }

    // Создаем категорию, если она еще не существует
    $term = term_exists($category, 'product_cat');
    if (!$term) {
        $term_id = wp_insert_term($category, 'product_cat');
        if (is_wp_error($term_id)) {
            echo 'Ошибка при создании категории: ' . $term_id->get_error_message();
            wp_die();
        }
    } else {
        $term_id = $term['term_id'];
    }

    // Создаем атрибуты
    $attributes = array(
        'active' => 'Active',
        'packs' => "Pack"
    );

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $label) {
        $attribute_exists = taxonomy_exists($attribute);
        if (!$attribute_exists) {
            $attribute_id = wc_create_attribute(array(
                'name' => $attribute,
                'label' => $label,
                'slug' => sanitize_title($attribute),
                'type' => 'select',
                'order_by' => 'menu_order',
                'has_archives' => 1
            ));

        } else {
            $attribute_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name($attribute);
        }

        // Привязываем атрибут к категории
        $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
        if ($attribute_taxonomies) {
            foreach ($attribute_taxonomies as $attribute_taxonomy) {
                if ($attribute_taxonomy->attribute_name === $attribute) {
                    $attribute_taxonomy_id = $attribute_taxonomy->attribute_id;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isset($attribute_taxonomy_id)) {
                $term_meta = get_option('taxonomy_' . $attribute_taxonomy_id);
                $term_meta[$term_id] = 1;
                update_option('taxonomy_' . $attribute_taxonomy_id, $term_meta);
            }
        }
    }
    // Парсим JSON
    $json_data = file_get_contents($link);
    $products = json_decode($json_data, true);

    foreach ($products as $product_id => $product_data) {
        $product_name = $product_data['name'];
        $product_active = $product_data['active'];
        $product_sinonim = $product_data['sinonim'];
        $product_analog = implode(",", $product_data['analog']);
        $product_desc = $product_data['desc'];
        $product_packs = $product_data['packs'];


        if ($product_analog == "" && $product_sinonim != "") {
            $product_desc = $product_desc . "\r\n" . $product_name . " other names: \r\n" . $product_sinonim . "\r\n" . $product_name . " analogs: None";
        }

        if ($product_sinonim == "" && $product_analog != "") {
            $product_desc = $product_desc . "\r\n" . $product_name . " other names: None" . "\r\n" . " analogs: \r\n" . $product_analog;
        }

        if ($product_sinonim == "" && $product_analog == "") {
            $product_desc = $product_desc . "\r\n" . $product_name . " other names: None" . "\r\n" . " analogs: None";
        }
        if ($product_sinonim != "" && $product_analog != ""){
        $product_desc = $product_desc . "\r\n" . $product_name . " other names: \r\n" . $product_sinonim . "\r\n" . $product_name . " analogs: \r\n" . $product_analog;
        }
        // Создаем товар
        $new_product = array(
            'post_title' => $product_name,
            'post_content' => $product_desc,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'product',
        );

        $product_id = wp_insert_post($new_product);

        // Устанавливаем категорию товара
        wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $category, 'product_cat');

        // Устанавливаем атрибуты товара


        wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $product_active, 'pa_active', true );

        $att_active = Array('pa_active' =>Array(
                'name'=>'pa_active',
                'value'=>$product_active,
                'is_visible' => '1',
                'is_taxonomy' => '1'
                ));

        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', $att_active);

        $dosages = array_keys($product_packs);

        foreach ($dosages as $dosage) {
            $packs = $product_packs[$dosage];        
            foreach ($packs as $packId => $packData) {
                $num = $packData['num'];
                $price = $packData['price'];
                $type = $packData['type'];

                $newName = $dosage . ' ' . $num . ' ' . $type;

                wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $newName, 'pa_packs', true );

                $att_packs = Array('pa_packs' =>Array(
                    'name'=>'pa_packs',
                    'value'=>$newName,
                    'is_visible' => '1',
                    'is_taxonomy' => '1',
                    'is_variation' => '1'
                ));
        
                update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', $att_packs);
      
            }
        }
        
    }

    echo 'Категория, атрибуты и продукты успешно созданы.';
    wp_die();
}
```